# Android - gson.fromJson not assigning just one field correctly

Tags: android, json, gson

I have a json array of about 60 objects, each having about 50 fields. when I use fromJson, it is assigning the values accurately to all fields except one, "stops". "stops" is getting filled with "-1". This is the json string part for "stops" and below that is the class snippet.

```
"carrierid": "SG",
"stops": "0",
"seatsavailable": "1",

@SerializedName("carrierid")
@Expose
private String carrierid;
@SerializedName("stops")
@Expose
private String stops;
@SerializedName("seatsavailable")
@Expose
private String seatsavailable;
```

Please let me know what I might be doing wrong.

```
{
 "data": {
  "returnflights": [
   {
    "origin": "TRV",
    "rating": 0,
    "DepartureTime": "",
    "flightcode": "3428",
    "Group": "",
    "farebasis": "LSAVER",
    "FlHash": "rSG-3428",
    "spicestatus": "Normal",
    "holdflag": "",
    "CINFO": "air-TRV-BLR-20171103--1-0-0-E-100--",
    "deptime": "17:20",
    "codeshare": "",
    "tickettype": "e",
    "ibibopartner": "spicejetnew",
    "productclass": "RS",
    "duration": "1h 35m",
    "platingcarrier": "",
    "qtype": "fbs",
    "carriercode": "SG",
    "flightno": "3428",
    "servicetype": "J",
    "fareclass": "L",
    "faresequence": "5",
    "destination": "BLR",
    "depterminal": "1",
    "carrierid": "SG",
    "stops": "0",
    "seatsavailable": "1",
    "state": "Clean",
    "arrterminal": "-",
    "provider": "",
    "PromotionId": "",
    "fare": {
     "grossamount": 5280,
     "totalbasefare": 4275,
     "adultbasefare": 4275,
     "totalfare": 5280,
     "totalsurcharge": 0,
     "totaltaxes": 1005,
     "adulttax": 1005,
     "adulttotalfare": 5280,
     "totalcommission": ""
    },
    "CabinClass": "",
    "fareapptype": "Route",
    "warnings": "Refundable",
    "ArrivalTime": "",
    "isallotmentmarketfare": "false",
    "onwardflights": [],
    "aircraftType": "DH8",
    "seatingclass": "E",
    "EticketFlag": "true",
    "faresellkey": "0~L~~LSAVER~2022~~5~X",
    "operatingcarrier": "",
    "std": "2017-11-03T17:20:00",
    "src": "",
    "sta": "2017-11-03T18:55:00",
    "ruleno": "2022",
    "splitduration": "1h 35m",
    "searchKey": "0:0:0:0:0:4275:0:5280:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:4275:5280:0:0:0:0:0:0",
    "bookingclass": "",
    "journeysellkey": "SG~3428~ ~~TRV~11/03/2017 17:20~BLR~11/03/2017 18:55~",
    "airline": "spicejet",
    "classofservice": "L",
    "multicitysearch": "",
    "depdate": "2017-11-03t1720",
    "arrtime": "18:55",
    "arrdate": "2017-11-03t1855",
    "TravelTime": ""
   },
   {
    "origin": "TRV",
    "rating": 0,
    "DepartureTime": "",
    "flightcode": "874",
    "Group": "",
    "farebasis": "T0IP",
    "FlHash": "r6E-874",
    "spicestatus": "Normal",
    "holdflag": "",
    "CINFO": "air-TRV-BLR-20171103--1-0-0-E-100--",
    "deptime": "07:50",
    "codeshare": "",
    "tickettype": "e",
    "ibibopartner": "indigonew",
    "productclass": "R",
    "duration": "1h 20m",
    "platingcarrier": "",
    "qtype": "fbs",
    "carriercode": "6E",
    "flightno": "874",
    "servicetype": "J",
    "fareclass": "T",
    "faresequence": "2",
    "destination": "BLR",
    "depterminal": "-",
    "carrierid": "6E",
    "stops": "0",
    "seatsavailable": "1",
    "state": "Clean",
    "arrterminal": "-",
    "provider": "",
    "PromotionId": "",
    "fare": {
     "grossamount": 3808,
     "totalbasefare": 2350,
     "adultbasefare": 2350,
     "totalfare": 3808,
     "totalsurcharge": 0,
     "totaltaxes": 1458,
     "adulttax": 1458,
     "adulttotalfare": 3808,
     "totalcommission": ""
    },
    "CabinClass": "",
    "fareapptype": "Route",
    "warnings": "Refundable",
    "ArrivalTime": "",
    "isallotmentmarketfare": "false",
    "onwardflights": [],
    "aircraftType": "320",
    "seatingclass": "E",
    "EticketFlag": "true",
    "faresellkey": "0~T~~T0IP~1059~~2~X",
    "operatingcarrier": "",
    "std": "2017-11-03T07:50:00",
    "src": "",
    "sta": "2017-11-03T09:10:00",
    "ruleno": "1059",
    "splitduration": "1h 20m",
    "searchKey": "0:0:0:0:0:2350:0:3808:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:2350:3808:0:0:0:0:0:0",
    "bookingclass": "",
    "journeysellkey": "6E~ 874~ ~~TRV~11/03/2017 07:50~BLR~11/03/2017 09:10~",
    "airline": "Indigo",
    "classofservice": "T",
    "multicitysearch": "",
    "depdate": "2017-11-03t0750",
    "arrtime": "09:10",
    "arrdate": "2017-11-03t0910",
    "TravelTime": ""
   }
  ]
 },
 "data_length": 2
}
```

Comment: could you please show us one json object?

Comment: could you check if you don't have the "stops" key repeated on the json?

Comment: I have updated the question with a json array that I have used.

Comment: IIRC, I had a similar issue once on gson 2.6 when the String field was final AND initialized inline in the declaration. Moving the initialization in the constructors solved it. Just food for thought, since your case seems different.

Comment: I had a similar thought but when I checked it seemed to be already in the same sequence of the json string